# Scrapy - How to get XPATH node as text

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to get a node as string from a XHTML node.

for example

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="myText"></input>
            <input type="text" value="myText" disabled="true"></input>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to get two input's XHTML text as string in an array, like this?

```
["<input type="text" value="myText"></input>"
"<input type="text" value="myText" disabled="true"></input>"]
```

Is this possible with scrapys XPATH selector?

Answer (score 1):

Not completely what you're asking for as it only shows the opening tag and for some reason it removes `="true"` from the last input, but it might be enough depending on what you're using it for.

```
>>> response.xpath('//div/input').extract()
[u'<input type="text" value="myText">', u'<input type="text" value="myText" disabled>']
```